# C macro to turn a pin on or off

Tags: c

I know it seems like this has been asked before but I spent a few hours looking for and testing things and couldn't find a solution.

I want to replace this:

```
#define LED_ON PORTA|=(1<<6)
#define LED_OFF PORTA&=~(1<<6)
```

with something that works like this:

```
#define ON 1
#define OFF 0
#define LED(x) if (x==ON) PORTA|=(1<<6) else if (x==OFF) PORTA&=~(1<<6)
```

So what is the right way (or best way?) to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
#define LED(x) (x==ON) ? (PORTA|=(1<<6)) : (PORTA&=~(1<<6))
```

EDIT: Slight error, I apologise. Is this what you're going for?

Comment: Yes! I tried several things but was definitely over complicating it. Minor edit, port assignments had to be in parenthesis i.e. (PORTA|=(1<<6))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator alternatively.

```
#define ON 1
#define OFF 0
#define LED(X)  (X)?(PORTA|=(1<<6)):(PORTA &= ~(1<<6));
```

You can to make it more generic macro by replacing the pin number as:

```
#define ON 1
#define OFF 0
#define LED(STATE, PIN) (STATE)?(PORTA|=(1<<PIN)):(PORTA &= ~(1<<PIN));
```

Also, You can make it generic for all ports by replacing the PortName as:

```
#define ON 1
#define OFF 0
#define LED(STATE, PORT, PIN)   (STATE)?(PORT|=(1<<PIN)):(PORT&=~(1<<PIN));
```

Comment: If it wasn't for the fact that these are distributed over different registers this would work well.

Comment: @hvguy, I have edited the answer and added the generic part for all ports