# C macro compiler warnings

Tags: c, avr, avr-gcc

I've defined a macro, using input from a previous question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422032/c-macro-to-turn-a-pin-on-or-off/53422243?noredirect=1#comment93731132_53422243). The macro is intended to either set, clear, or check a GPIO pins state.
The macro works as expected however a problem shows up when compiling. I get compiler warnings anywhere it's used:

> **Warning        right-hand operand of comma expression has no effect**

when I use the macro like this:

```
#define ON  1
#define OFF 2
#define ENA 3
#define OUT_3(x) (x==ON) ? (PORTJ.OUTSET=PIN2_bm) : (x==OFF) ? (PORTJ.OUTCLR=PIN2_bm) : (x==ENA) ? (PORTJ.DIRSET=PIN2_bm) : (PORTJ.DIRCLR=PIN2_bm)
#include <avr/io.h>

if (something) OUT_3(ENA);
```

However, if I do this:

```
if (something) {OUT_3(ENA);}
```

I no longer get the warnings.

Why is there a difference? How should I alter the macro to prevent this scenario?

Additionally this invokes the warning:

```
int i=0;
if (something) i=1, OUT_3(ENA);
```

However this does not:

```
int i=0;
if (something) OUT_3(ENA), i=1;
```

My understanding of comma separated expressions is clearly a bit off. How is the compiler seeing this? I looked at several other questions similar to this but still do not fully understand the difference.

Comment: Don't see a comma anywhere in the macro

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Parentheses are your friend. Use them.

Comment: The warning is from elsewhere.

Comment: Use `gcc -E` to see the complete expansion of the macro.

Comment: do you want `OUT_3`  to expand to an expression or a statement? If it is a statement, use `do`  .... `while(0)`  around it.

Comment: With any sane MCU family you wouldn't even begin to considering pure evil macros like these. Only on Atmel...

Comment: I tested your code `avr-gcc -Wall pgm.c` and I had no warning. But without full code, it is difficult. So I used in my code : `#define __AVR_ATxmega128A1__` before the `#include <avr/io.h>` and `typedef enum { ON=1,OFF=0,ENA=2 } myState_t;` and in main `if (1) OUT_3(ENA);`

Comment: Looks like choosing a macro over a function here is perhaps not the best approach. I have use the do ... while(0) approach as well but have the same error problem.

Answer (score 5):

That macro is nasty for several reasons:

1. Macro parameters should always be surrounded with parenthesis to avoid potential problems with operator precedence. Change `(x==ON)` to `((x)==ON)`.
2. Nested ternary operations should be surrounded with parenthesis to make execution order obvious. Change `a ? b : c ? d : e` to `a ? b : (c ? d : e)`.
3. Complete macro should be surrounded with parentheses `#define MACRO (...)` or do-while-zero loop `#define MACRO do {...} while(0)` to avoid possible problems with operator precedence. More below.
4. Ternary operator is not really useful here as you are not using it's return value. You should rather use regular if or switch statements. This is where previously mentioned do-while-zero loop becomes handy:

   ```
   #define OUT_3(x) \
       do { \
           if((x) == ON)       { PORTJ.OUTSET = PIN2_bm; } \
           else if((x) == OFF) { PORTJ.OUTCLR = PIN2_bm; } \
           else if((x) == ENA) { PORTJ.DIRSET = PIN2_bm; } \
           else                { PORTJ.DIRCLR = PIN2_bm; } \
       } while(0)
   ```
5. But is macro really even necessary? You could use inline function instead, and get rid of all macro weirdness:

   ```
   static inline void OUT_3(x_type x) {
       if(x == ON)       { PORTJ.OUTSET = PIN2_bm; }
       else if(x == OFF) { PORTJ.OUTCLR = PIN2_bm; }
       else if(x == ENA) { PORTJ.DIRSET = PIN2_bm; }
       else              { PORTJ.DIRCLR = PIN2_bm; }
   }
   ```

With these changes, your error will likely go away, and your code is much easier to read.

Comment: Macros are nasty because they look like syntactic units but are really sequences of tokens. OUT_3(x) looks like a function but can have all sorts of weird side effects including on surrounding code. Even proposal 4 above is a trap. if `x` is an expression with side-effects `x` is evaluated between 1 and 3 times but only once in proposal 5.
You seem to be passing in a value (`ENA`) here but if you proliferate this style one day you'll provoke some weird bug due to a side-effect buried in a heap of macros. 
You haven't earned your C spurs until you've be 'had' by a bizarre macro side-effect.

Comment: This may very well be what I am experiencing. Is it then reasonable for me to assume this is not the place for a macro and switch to using functions to accomplish my goal?

Comment: @hvguy With what I'm seeing, there seems to be no benefit for using macro. In these cases it's safer to default to using regular function.

Comment: @user694733 Thanks. I'll re-evaluate my macros. I generally try to keep these basic pin manipulation functions as macros but if it causes problem then no reason not to switch.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your issue. This code works without any problem

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
enum type{ON, OFF, ENA};

#define OUT_3(x) (x==ON) ? (printf("ON\n")) : (x==OFF) ? (printf("OFF\n")) : (x==ENA) ? (printf("ENA\n")) : (printf("OTHER\n"))

int main(){
  int a = 2;
  if(a == 1) OUT_3(ON);
  if(a == 2) OUT_3(OFF);
  if(a == 3) OUT_3(ENA);

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with

```
gcc -Wall -O0 -g -o main main.c
```

Could you please show how the definitions of ON, OFF, ENA and the Port definitions look like?

Comment: Edited to show additional information. The port defines are the standard included for avr xmega and can be replaced with others while still producing a similar result.

Comment: You are still missing the definitions of `PIN2_bm`, `PORTJ.DIRCLR`, `PORTJ.DIRSET` and so on